# Using NodeJS, Bower and GulpJS in a project, what should I exclude from my Git repository?

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, bower

I recently started working on a web project. I'm using:

- NodeJS as a server
- Bower - to get all the dependencies
- GulpJS - for build and other tasks
- Git - to save my work

For simplicity, let's say that I'm only writing HTML/CSS/JavaScript.
It doesn't seem to make sense to save ALL the project files in Git including external JavaScript libraries, since I only want to save the core files (the files that I created and modified myself).

On the other hand, if I want to hand over the project to another developer and I only hand him my own files without all the dependencies and libraries, how will he know which dependencies to get? How will he be able to build and run the project?
(I'm still new to bower, gulp and node)

So, what files do I need to save in my repository (the minimum number of files) to be able to build and work on the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what you said, your `.gitignore` file should look like this :

```
node_modules
bower_components
dist
.tmp
```

> On the other hand, if I want to hand over the project to another developer and I only hand him my own files without all the dependencies and libraries, how will he know which dependencies to get?

You don't include your dependencies such as the `node_modules` and `bower_components` but the `package.json` and `bower.json` are tracking those dependencies so that when a new user makes a clone, he only has to `npm install` and `bower install`.

This is, if you took care to use the `--save` or `--save-dev` flags when you npm or bower install new packages.

Comment: I wouldn't ignore node_modules. You never know when an included module might disappear. Its best to have them under version control.

Comment: Versionning `node_modules` is considered bad practice, use npm-shrinkwrap instead - source npm doc https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem if I unpublish a npm module. You are basically stuck without a copy.

Comment: "If you are paranoid about depending on the npm ecosystem, you should run a private npm mirror or a private cache." https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git (you have to think about the platform specific modules, the ones made in c++ that need to be rebuild whether you are on Linux, Windows, MacOS X ...)

Comment: @topheman Are there known issues with npm's modules when switching between OS's? Have you encountered any?

Comment: Not all node modules are fully implemented in js, some are part C++ (so they need to be compiled on your computer, this is the `node-gyp` part you can see sometimes). So if you install one of those modules on a linux and share them "as is" with a windows, it won't work, but if you just share the package.json, it will correctly install and rebuild from source for the correct platform.

Comment: @topheman exactly. I was working with a developer using a Mac and I was on PC. Some packages where totally broken I had to remove all the packages everytime and reinstall them again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite active repository on github, containing predefined `.gitignore` files for different languages, platforms and buildtools.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Although there's no *bower-* or *gulp-specific* configuration there (yet), I usually find it quite useful when trying new things.